# Show hidden files and Sort the result in windows search

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-search

I am using Windows search using command. The command is

```
"explorer search-ms:"
```

It has many options like searching file names, extensions, type of files etc.

But I want to have these options,

1. Search hidden files
2. Sort the result of output window in Name, Date Modified and Size wise.

Is this possible in search-ms: command ?

Or is there any ways to implement the same using windows command ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command to search for hidden files

dir  /s /p /A:H

Attribute details:

/s - to search
/p - to pause at result
/A:H - to search hidden files

To sort use following attributes

/O:N   Name
  /O:S   file Size
  /O:E   file Extension
  /O:D   Date & time

Comment: this will search within command prompt. I want to see the result in windows explorer.